# How to build a custom snippet in Brackets ?

Tags: adobe-brackets

I have just shifted from Atom text editor to Brackets , both are experimental and quite new i know :) , well i have a very basic question. Bracket definitly seems more refined and has been on the block for a longer time. Now in atom i used to create custom sinppets like so:

```
".source.html":
     "HTML snippet":
        "prefix": "spithtml"
           "body": """<!doctype html>
            <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8">
                    <meta name="description" content="">
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                    <title>Title here</title>
                    <link rel="author" href="humans.txt">
                </head>

                <body>

                </body>

                    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

                </body>
            </html>
            """
```

How would i create a simple HTML snippet in Brackets ? Thats my question , i surfed the net alot , some aspects of brackets is quite well Documented, some are not , I really can't find any documentation on how to create a custom snippet in Brackets , as that would really help my workflow.

Can anybody tell me how would i go about building a custom snippet in Brackets ?

Thank you.

Alex-z.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure but probably you only need something like this:
https://github.com/chuyik/brackets-snippets